# Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and Message: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

**I'm trying to display an average result from the database to the view but I keep getting this error:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Warning
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
> Filename: kmeans/pengelompokan_v.php
> Line Number: 228
>
> Backtrace:
> File: C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\skripsi\application\views\kmeans\pengelompokan_v.php
> Line: 228
> Function: _error_handler
> File: C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\skripsi\application\libraries\Layouts.php
> Line: 15
> Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\skripsi\application\controllers\Pengelompokan.php
> Line: 27
> Function: load
> File: C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\skripsi\index.php
> Line: 315 Function: require_once

And

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Warning
> Message: Message:  Array to string conversion
> Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php
> Line Number: 2442
> Backtrace:
> File: C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\skripsi\application\models\Datamining_m.php
> Line: 31
> Function: get
> File: C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\skripsi\application\controllers\Pengelompokan.php
> Line: 17
> Function: by_year
> File: C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\skripsi\index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

[image: controller]

[image: view]

[image: model]

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Don't post pics of code, post your actual code here.